# errors when splitting implementation and header

Tags: c++, windows

I have created a functional OOP program that uses a bunch of classes, and I am getting a bunch of errors that don't make sense. I am working on a Windows VC++ 2008 project, and at the start I tried to have different implementation, and header files. when I tried to for example make a 
object1.cpp

```
#ifndef Object1_cpp
#define Object1_cpp

#include "Object1.h"

Object1::Object1(){
   ...
}
Object1::~Object1(){
   ...
}
....
#endif
```

object1.h

```
#ifndef Object1_H
#define Object1_h
class Object1{
public: Object1();
public: ~Object1(); // line 39 of object1.h
...
};
#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "object1.cpp"
```

sometimes this returns errors of

```
1>c:...\object1.h(39) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
1>c:...\object1.h(39) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

and since it is not complaining about the constructor the only thing that comes to mind would be the '~' indicating the destructor. when I take the .h out of the picture changing the .cpp to be

```
#ifndef Object1_H
#define Object1_h
class Object1{
public: Object1::Object1();
public: Object1::~Object1();
...
};
#endif
```

or

```
#ifndef Object1_H
#define Object1_h
class Object1{
public: Object1();
public: ~Object1();
...
};
#endif
```

it compiles fine. I don't understand it. when I have done something similar in the past on other compilers it works fine, but it doesn't here.
currently the program is fully functional while I ignore the existence of the .h files, and do everything in the .cpp files. it seems like the compiler throws an issue with the Til-de operator denoting the destructor. this is just one example of the problem, and it occurs in all of my classes when I try to split up the implementation, and forward references.

found solution. apparently one of my team mates used the same #define in one of his files (because it made sense but wasn't the name of the file as convention was required)

Comment: You don't need `public:` for each function. After `public:`, all declared functions and variables are public until the scope is changed (with e.g. `private:` or `protected:`).

Comment: defining public, private, and protected for each thing actually comes from my experience with java, but no matter the compiler does not cause any issue, and is a subset standard not a primary. if that was the problem then why would it work when I have them in a single file, and not the header

Comment: non of the answers given address the question. they are simply rhetoric to style conventions.

Comment: I did a copy/paste of the code you supplied, and get no errors. The error must be because of something you do not show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include guards are broken:

```
#ifndef Object1_H
#define Object1_h
```

You have a `_H` at the end of one and an `_h` at the end of the other. This causes the include guard not to work.

Also, you don't need, and don't want, include guards in your implementation files. They should never be included by anything anyway.

Comment: thank you for that observation, but fixing that does not change the error that I am receiving

Comment: error is similar to observation, but resides in another file that uses the same #define (was done against applied project standards of using file name as guard)

Answer (score 2):

1. You do not need guards in the cpp file. The `#ifndef/#define/#endif` is only necessary in the header.
2. You can actually use a `#pragma once` for guarding.
3. Do not include cpp files, only headers. Your main.cpp should have a `#include "object11.h"`

Comment: Headers are included, source-files are compiled and linked.

Comment: `#pragma once` is not portable

Comment: you need a #include if you are physically directing the compiler to include something, and realistically if ever there is a chance that something might be included twice you should have guards on it. it was true in C its true in C++, and this does not even touch the question

Comment: @gardian06: This does indeed touch, and perhaps answer, the question: including the source file may very well be the cause of the problem, although it's hard to guess from the fragments of code you've posted.

Comment: I know prama once is not portable, however, this was a "Windows VC++ 2008 project"

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you use the scope in your constructor and destructor declarations:

```
class Object1{
public: Object1::Object1();
// Here ^^^^^^^^^
```

Inside a class (or struct) you don't need that:

```
class Object1 {
public:
    Object1();
    ~Object1();
};
```

Comment: that should not make a direct difference, and could be language dependent. I do this because of my experience with java.

Comment: @gardian06 It do make a difference, you actually noted the difference yourself in your question. Inside a class you should not use the scope-operator (`::`) when declaring member functions or variables. And yes it's definitely language dependent, you can not use the syntax of another language, no matter how similar, and expect it to work the same way if at all.